# How to change value of DateTimePicker inside ValueChanged event handler

Tags: c#, datetimepicker

I tried to change datetimepicker value if the datetime is bigger than today's date.

I tried to write a method after value changed, that changed the value but it's making a loop because I change the date value to today's date.

How can I fix this method?

(the loop happen if the if answer is true, when the `dateTimePickerUntil` value change, it repeat on the method)

```
private void dateTimePickerUntil_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show(dateTimePickerUntil.Value.ToString());
    if(dateTimePickerUntil.Value > DateTime.Now.Date)
    {
        dateTimePickerUntil.Value = DateTime.Now.Date;
        untildate = Convert.ToDateTime(dateTimePickerUntil.Value.ToShortDateString());
    }
    else
    {
        untildate = Convert.ToDateTime(dateTimePickerUntil.Value.ToShortDateString());
    }
}
```

Comment: Well, does not matter.  Just delete the useless MessageBox.Show() call.

Comment: I know that still work but it isnt the right way

Answer (score 0):

Break the loop: You only need to check `dateTimePickerUntil.Value` if `untildate != dateTimePickerUntil.Value`. The trick is to change `untildate` first, so that `untildate` already contains the right value before the next `ValueChanged` event occurs.

```
private void dateTimePickerUntil_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (dateTimePickerUntil.Value != untildate)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(dateTimePickerUntil.Value.ToString());
        if (dateTimePickerUntil.Value > DateTime.Today)
        {
            untildate = DateTime.Today; // Set first, so we can compare on the next event.
            dateTimePickerUntil.Value = DateTime.Today;
        }
        else
       {
          untildate = dateTimePickerUntil.Value;                
       }
   }
}
```